# GLFW-style infinite mouse movement in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, glfw

GLFW has a function which does exactly what I need:

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

This function lets the mouse to move freely without being bounded to the window or the screen.

One solution I found is to reset the mouse position each frame using:

```
 SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(window, defaultMousePositionX, defaultMousePositionY);
```

But I would still like to know If there is something like `glfwSetInputMode()` in SDL2.

Comment: Is this not the default behaviour? You can normally just move the mouse outside of the window, like any other application.

Comment: @DingusKhan AFAICT this is about relative (not absolute) mouse movement. Think FPS.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. Needed the clarification. I've answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you require relative movement, FPS style, SDL has a `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode` function [as seen here](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode). This forces SDL to only report motion events, so the mouse position doesn't change.

Another method would be to track the current and next positions yourself and manually calculating the differential, to get the distance moved.

```
// Last position
lastX = currX;
lastY = currY;

// Current position
currX = event.motion.x;
currY = event.motion.y;

// Motion
motionX = currX - lastX;
motionY = currY - lastY;
```

This could translate smoothly to other control methods too, like analogue sticks and touch controls, giving you a more uniform experience should you decide to use other platforms.

Comment: Even with SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode the mouse movement is limited by the window's size, in glfw there is no limit.

Comment: Any recent information regarding this function? I'm facing the same issue and I still cannot find a way that simulates the glfw function equivalent.